# Counting states for Peg Solitaire 2^33 != Riemann Sum i = 1, n = 33 (nCi)?

Tags: combinations, riemann-sum, finite-state-machine

So I have this question that is finding all states (not possible states just states if this game didn't have rules) for a game of Peg Solitaire.

For those unaware of what it is: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bt6GpGvUNeQ.

I understand that 2^33 will get all states because there are 33 slots in the game and they can either be filled with a peg or empty (hence where the 2 comes from because 2 states), but is that not the same as getting the Riemann sum of the combinations of empty slots on the board?

Comment: sorry I removed "possible states" cause it would be much less than than 2^33-2. You are correct but there are also states not possible to get to that we'd have to factor in as well. So sorry that should be "states" not "possible states"

Comment: I don't understand your question.  If you are asking whether or not $2^{33} \neq \sum\limits_{i=1}^{33}\binom{33}{i}$, that is correct because what is actually correct is $2^{33}=\sum\limits_{i=\color{red}{0}}^{33}\binom{33}{i}$.  If your question is how many ways you can have a board filled with some collection of pegs... if you don't consider symmetry and you don't care about whether they are legal achievable game-states, then $2^{33}$.  If you start ignoring certain states such as "all slots filled" or "no slots filled", then you'll subtract those states from the total as desired.

Comment: If you are interested in actually counting the number of legal achievable game-states, that seems like an absurdly difficult problem, probably best left to brute force counting via computer.

Comment: so 2^33 does equal ∑i=0, n=33(33i)? I'm curious why this is if you don't mind telling me

Comment: The more general result is https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem and you can plug in 1 for both x and y.  Without using that though, it can be proven using double-counting.  On the one hand by using multiplication principle by asking whether each peg individually is included or not yielding 2^33.  On the other hand you can break apart by cases and add up the number of ways you have $i$ pegs where i ranges from 0 to 33, noting the number of ways to have i pegs is counted using binomial coefficients.  Since they both correctly count the same thing they must be equal.